# regular expressions for random letters/symbols

Tags: java, regex

I have searched for hours using regular expression generators and checkers but i cant seem to get it to work...

I have this string: `hdr("");cr(92);cl(3,"",4,"420720250","random message here");etr();`

and so far my code is :

```
private void strchecker() {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{9})");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strLine);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); //prints /{item}/
    } else {
        //System.out.println("Match not found");
    }

}
```

This code is working and it finds the 9 digit number in the string. What im trying to do it find the regex code to search for "cl(3" or "cl(2", if it exists then send the 9 digit number to a variable. i just don't know how to find that cl(3 or 2..

any advice?

Thanks
Matt

Comment: You can't just use `cl\\(\\d`?

Comment: excellent! that found the cl( but i need it 2 or 3, but not 1

Comment: `cl\\([23]`?  how about that?

Comment: :D youvee made my day! what took me hours took you less than 1 minute. I guess i have to study regex more... I'm off to try and figure out the rest of the code :D thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/cl\([23].*(\d{9})/
```

The final parentheses will capture the 9 digits in group 1.

Comment: Hi, doesn't work :( is there a way to convert this to work in javascript?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work?"  It seems to work just fine for me... `'hdr("");cr(92);cl(3,"",4,"420720250","random message here");etr();'.match(/cl\([23].*(\d{9})/)[1]` -- you can even do this in the console of your browser

Comment: I used that exact code but in eclipse it says "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )"

Comment: @user2078674 I see you mean *java*, not JavaScript.  Big difference!  You need to escape the backslash (type `\\d`)

Answer (score 0):

Since you note you're using javascript, I think you could do it like this, as you can't use lookbehind; you just have to grab the capture group rather than use the full match.

```
cl\\([23].*?(\\d{9})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! but i am using javascript :p